# python pandas 2つのcsvの共通の列の値を使って結合したい

Tags: python, pandas

以下のような２つのデータフレームがあり、new_dfのようにしたいです。
idはインデックスではありません。

[df1]
id,value
1,A
2,B
3,NaN
4,NaN
105,A
...

[df2]
value,param1,param2
A,df2-1,Value-1
B,Df2-2,VAlue-2
C,dF2-3,valUE-3
D,DF2-4,valuE-4
...

[df3]
id,param1,param2
1,id-1,DF3-1
2,Id-2,Df3-2
3,iD-3,dF3-3
5,ID-5,df3-5
...

↓　↓　↓

[new_df]
id,value,param1
1,A,df2-1,Value-1
2,B,Df2-2,VAlue-2
3,iD-3,dF3-3
4,NaN,NaN,NAN
105,A,df2-1,Value-1
...

df1でvalueがあればdf2のvalueに該当するparam1,param2を、
df1でvalueがなければdf3のidに該当するparam1,param2を、
df1でvalueもidも該当するものがなければそのままにしておきたいです。

sqldfを使えば力業で出来るのは分かっているのですが、そのためにfor ...iterrows()を使いたくありません。
うまい実現方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんな感じでどうでしょうか？

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,105],
                    'value': ['A','B',np.nan,np.nan,'A']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value': ['A','B','C','D'],
                    'param1':['df2-1','df2-2','df2-3','df2-4'],
                    'param2':['value-1','value-2','value-3','value-4']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,5],
                    'param1':['id-1','id-2','id-3','id-5'],
                    'param2':['df3-1','df3-2','df3-3','df3-5']})

ret = df1.merge(df2, on='value', how='left').combine_first(df1.merge(df3, 
on='id'))
print(ret)
#    id value param1   param2
#0    1     A  df2-1  value-1
#1    2     B  df2-2  value-2
#2    3   NaN   id-3    df3-3
#3    4   NaN    NaN      NaN
#4  105     A  df2-1  value-1
```

Comment: ありがとうございます、これで出来ました。
df1.update[(df2, df3....)]
のような方法も検討していましたが、こちらの方が良さそうです。
（combineなんてあったんですね、知らなかったです。）

Comment: @nomura さん、解決したのであれば回答を承認することができます :)